# Using data from GET request without user's page reloading

Tags: node.js, express, get, socket.io

So, the subject is one-page web app on Node.js + express + ejs + socket.io + mongoose all the latest versions.

let's imagine user inputs in his browser's adress bar "www.app.com/**data**". I want to grab response from db according to this **data**, send it back to user and render for him basic 'www.app.com' page with  implemented in it db response.

I'm curious about two options: what is the best way to do this with and without page reloading, for example if user is already on the page and I do not want to reload it - just change accordingly to db response.

I can grab this data from his get request:

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
     console.log('got' + req.params.id); 
     ///some db magic here... poof, response ready///   
})
```

But then what I do next? I was thinking about sending response by `sockets.io`, which I am using anyway, but then how can I just end this GET without any reloading of user's page? If i must send something back, I can respond by render this page again with ejs, but then I can't rely on sokets, cos while reloading - he is disconnected from them.

Can you shed a light on my confusion?

Comment: You can create two routes. One which will be fired if user first enter to the page (page + data), second which will be fired by your code when user should get new data from database (only data).

Comment: but HOW can i give him only data without reloading his page?

Comment: Create a [xmlhttprequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) in your client side. Your node should have route which handle this request and send a json with data.

Comment: as i understand i need to make this request and send it through JS. I can do the same via Sockets which is much more comfortable for me. Instead in the question im talking about the case when i recieve get from users browser adress bar - i.e user type in his adrees bar something, hit enter - get request flyes to me

Comment: When user will type yourpage/123 in browser address bar and will hit enter then your first node route will catch this request and will send a page,  page will have some js code which will be fired on the initialization and will ask (second request) server about your db data. This piece of code can be also fired when user will have to get a new data from db

Comment: Therefore if there is 1st request even from alrdy loaded page i need to reload whole thing anyway, but yes option that you describet is sims like legit, yet i need then to insert somehow this id after fist call into pages js with ejs to call with it to server again... or just get it from adress bar via js

Comment: btw just now stumbled on the fragment url, thought maybe it gonna be better to use # fragments to pass data to js through it and then do a 2nd call

Comment: If you are using frameworks like angular or react it is very easy to get a parameters from routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I'm using `URI Fragment identifier` i.e `#` in URI.
If user inputs `http://YourAwesomeApp/#hashtag` you can catch `hashtag` by using this listener:

```
window.onhashchange = function () {        
        var hash = location.hash.substr(location.hash.indexOf("#") + 1);
        //now hash = hashtag, do your stuff.      
};
```

It perfectly fits my needs.

Be aware, that `window.onhashchange` also fires if you change hash via JS (`location.hash = something`).